# Find the tetrahedron with smallest volume

Tags: calculus

Pass such a plane through point $P(a, b, c)$ that the volume of the tetrahedron between this plane and the coordinate planes is the smallest.

I have no idea how we can find it. Can you please help for solution?

Comment: So far both posts of you have been problem-statement questions. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can assume WLOG that $(a,b,c)$ is in the first octant (i.e., with positive coordinates.
The general equation of a plane $(\Pi)$ intersecting axes $Ox, Oy, Oz$ in $u, \ v, \ w \ > \ 0$ resp. is :

$$\dfrac{x}{u}+\dfrac{y}{v}+\dfrac{z}{w}=1\tag{1}$$

As this plane passes through $P(a,b,c)$, we have the constraint :

$$\underbrace{\dfrac{a}{u}+\dfrac{b}{v}+\dfrac{c}{w}-1}_{f(u,v,w)}=0\tag{2}$$

Therefore, as the volume of tetrahedron $OABC$ (where $A(u,0,0), \ B(0,v,0), \ C(0,0,w)$ is

$$\dfrac16 OA \times OB \times OC = \underbrace{\dfrac16 uvw}_{g(u,v,w)}\tag{3}$$

Let us write that a minimization occurs (necessary condition) if the gradients of $f$ and $g$ are proportionnal :

$$\begin{cases}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\lambda \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u}\\ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v}=\lambda \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v}\\\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial w}=\lambda \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial w}\end{cases} \ \ \iff \ \ \begin{cases}
a/u^2&=& \lambda vw\\
b/v^2&=& \lambda uw\\
c/w^2&=& \lambda uv\\
\end{cases}$$

(factor $-1/6$ has been incorporated into factor $\lambda$).

$$\lambda uvw = \dfrac{a}{u}= \dfrac{b}{v}= \dfrac{c}{w}$$

which can be written in the following way :

$$ \begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{pmatrix}=\mu\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}\tag{4}$$

for a certain $mu$. Plugging the results of (4) into (1), one gets : $\mu=3$ giving $u=3a, \ v=3b, \ w=3c$.

The minimal plane has therefore the equation

$$\dfrac{x}{a}+\dfrac{y}{b}+\dfrac{z}{c}=3\tag{1}$$

It remains to check that the necessary condition is as well a sufficient condition, i.e., that it is indeed a minimum that has been found...

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: No comment ?....

Comment: By the way, it seems that a proper title should be "Find the tetrahedron with smallest volume".

Comment: I have added the missing steps, being understood that you have to check that it's a minimum. (please note the positivity conditions added as well).

Comment: Thank you very much. But could you do my last step? I couldn't seriously do it. Don't do it, it's up to you, thank you.

Comment: I have completely written back my solution in a much simpler way.

Comment: Thank you very much.